# Como fazer uma media de N números maiores que 6

Tags: c

Tenho que fazer um programa em C que mostre no final a média dos N números maiores que 6, porém já esgotei minhas ideias sobre como resolver isso.

O que consegui fazer até agora foi isto:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    int n,maior,menor,media;

    do
    {
        scanf ("%d",&n);
        if (n>maior)

            maior=n;
        if (n<menor && n!=0)

            menor=n;

    } while (n != 0);
    media = n/n;
    printf("%d e o maior\n",maior);
    printf("%d e o menor\n",menor);
    for (int i = 0; i => 6 && i<maior; ++i)
    {
        media = n/i;
    }
    printf("%d e a media\n",media);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Seu código não compila. `=>` não é válido na linguagem. Você também não inicializou a variável `maior` antes do primeiro `if`. E a divisão é inteira, portanto você não conseguirá tirar a média desse jeito

Comment: Se você compartilhou o seu pensamento, talvez seja mais fácil te ajudar, mostrar onde estão os problemas no algoritmo e como transformar em código

Comment: Se a divisão n/n der um resultado diferente de 1 certamente você estará com um tremendo bug!

Answer (score 3):

Saber qual é o maior ou qual é o menor número não te interessa. O seu programa não precisa disso.

Dentro desse `do-while`, você poderia ler um número e se ele for maior que 6 (use um `if`), então somar em uma variável `soma` e aumentar o `i`. Se não, pula e deixa pra lá (ou seja, não coloque nenhum `else`). No final, bastaria mandar um `printf` em `((double) soma) / i`.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode implementar uma função capaz de calcular a [média aritmética](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9dia_aritm%C3%A9tica) de um vetor de inteiros usando **somente** os elementos que possuem um valor abaixo do limite estabelecido, veja só:

```
double media( int v[], int tam, int limite )
{
    int i = 0;
    double n = 0.0;
    int soma = 0;
    double med = 0.0;

    for( i = 0; i < tam; i++ )
    {
        if( v[i] > limite )
        {
            soma += v[i];
            n++;
        }
    }

    med = soma / n;

    return med;
}
```

Para se determinar o maior e o menor valor contidos em um vetor de inteiros você pode implementar funções específicas:

```
int maior( int v[], int tam )
{
    int i = 0;
    int n = INT_MIN;

    for( i = 0; i < tam; i++ )
        if( v[i] > n )
            n = v[i];

    return n;
}

int menor( int v[], int tam )
{
    int i = 0;
    int n = INT_MAX;

    for( i = 0; i < tam; i++ )
        if( v[i] < n )
            n = v[i];

    return n;
}
```

Colocando tudo junto:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

double media( int v[], int tam, int limit )
{
    int i = 0;
    double n = 0.0;
    int soma = 0;
    double med = 0.0;

    for( i = 0; i < tam; i++ )
    {
        if( v[i] < limit )
        {
            soma += v[i];
            n++;
        }
    }

    med = soma / n;

    return med;
}

int maior( int v[], int tam )
{
    int i = 0;
    int n = INT_MIN;

    for( i = 0; i < tam; i++ )
        if( v[i] > n )
            n = v[i];

    return n;
}

int menor( int v[], int tam )
{
    int i = 0;
    int menor = INT_MAX;

    for( i = 0; i < tam; i++ )
        if( v[i] < menor )
            menor = v[i];

    return menor;
}

int main( void )
{
    int vet[] = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 1 };
    int tam = sizeof(vet) / sizeof(int);

    printf("Maior: %d\n", maior( vet, tam ) );
    printf("Menor: %d\n", menor( vet, tam ) );
    printf("Media: %g\n", media( vet, tam, 6 ) );

    return 0;
}
```

Saída:

```
Maior: 10
Menor: 1
Media: 2.66667
```

Comment: A média pode não ser inteira.

Comment: @VictorStafusa: Bem observado! Segue edição.